# how to join a standard table with a temporary one

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I try to join a standard table with a temporary one :

This is what i tried :

```
with temp1 as (
select * from table T )

select * from temp1, t2.field
left join temp1 t2 on temp1.id1 = t2.id2
```

It doesn't work properly. Any ideas ?

Thank you all.

Comment: This part, ", t2.field" is in the from clause which is giving you a syntax error.  Depending on what you want, perhaps it should be in the select clause.

Comment: Perhaps just an example but using a CTE that is simply defined as a full table `WITH temp1 AS (SELECT * FROM Table)` seems pretty pointless?

Comment: it was just an example of what im trying to do. I've realized that the jointure with the temp tables doesnt show the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for sql is select from where.  What you've written here reads select from select from.  Move the t2.field out of the from clause and into the select.

```
with temp1 as (
select * from table T )

select temp1.*, t2.field from temp1
left join temp1 t2 on temp1.id1 = t2.id2
```

Comment: +1 not the first correct answer, but at least attempted to provide an explanation with the answer and didn't just post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH TEMP1 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLET)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      TEMP1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON ( TEMP1.ID1 = T2.ID2 )
```